# Can I add members of a group to another group automatically?

Tags: permissions, groups

Is there a way to ensure that when a user is added to a permissions group on a system, that user is automatically added to one or more other defined groups?

For example adding a user to a group created as `netadmin` would add the user to the groups `www-data`, `tomcat`, `sambashare` and `ftp`. (This is only a hypothetical situation)

Another example group of `vmadmin` could add a user to the groups, `kvm`, `libvirt` and `vboxusers`.

I know that a group cannot be added to a group, but would like to avoid having to set up and maintain ACLs for different directories and files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do that.

However there's a pretty easy solution: you could add a function to `~/.bashrc` to wrap the whole task into a single command.

## Listing the sets of groups in a `case` statement (ok for a few sets of groups)

```bsh
function add_user {
    [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -z "$2" ] || return
    case "$1" in
    netadmin)
        groups=(netadmin www-data tomcat sambashare ftp)
        ;;
    vmadmin)
        groups=(kvm libvirt vboxusers)
        ;;
    *)
        printf "Group '%s' is not listed.\n" "$1"
        return
    esac
    printf "Adding '%s' to group '%s'...\n" "$2" "$1"
    usermod -aG ${groups[@]} "$1"
}
```

After that running e.g. `add_user netadmin user` will add `user` to `netadmin`, `www-data`, `tomcat`, `sambashare` and `ftp`, and running e.g. `add_user vmadmin user` will add `user` to `kvm`, `libvirt` and `vboxusers`.

Adding other sets of groups would be as easy as adding other entries to the `case` statement after the `vmadmin` entry and before the `*` entry:

```bsh
foo)
    groups=(bar foobar raboof)
    ;;
```

## Listing the sets of groups in an external configuration file

Create a file named `config` in `~/` whith the following content:

```
netadmin,netadmin,www-data,tomcat,sambashare,ftp
vmadmin,kvm,libvirt,vboxusers
```

- The first field identifies the name of the set of groups
- The fields after the first identify the groups to which the user is to add

```bsh
function add_user {
    [ ! -z "$1" -a ! -z "$2" ] || exit
    groups=( $(awk -F , -v group="$1" '$1==group {$1=""; print; exit}' config) )
    if [ ${#groups} -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "Group '%s' is not listed.\n" "$1"
        return
    fi
    printf "Adding '%s' to group '%s'...\n" "$2" "$1"
    usermod -aG ${groups[@]} "$1"
}
```

After that running e.g. `add_user netadmin user` will add `user` to `netadmin`, `www-data`, `tomcat`, `sambashare` and `ftp`, and running e.g. `add_user vmadmin user` will add `user` to `kvm`, `libvirt` and `vboxusers`.

Adding other sets of groups would be as easy as adding another entry to `~/config`:

```
foo,bar,foobar,raboof
```

Comment: That looks marvellous. I could create a separate function for each group that links to other groups. Would it be difficult to have the function read a config file, so that I wouldn't need a separate function for each?

Comment: @Arronical I don't think so, but you'll need to do some parsing. Do you have so many to add? If not it would probably be faster / cleaner to expand the function to use a `case` statement to determine what to do based on the arguments (e.g. `add_user netadmin user` would add `user` to the groups listed above, `add_user foo user` would add user to another custom defined group of groups etc.). If you add another example I can modify the function so that it can work for multiple groups of groups.

Comment: @Arronical I edited the function so that it handles both groups of groups and explained briefly how to add other groups. Anyway I think it would be interesting to make it work with a configuration file like you suggested, so I'm currently looking into that as well, I'll ping you when I have something.

Comment: @Arronical Done, it was easier than it looked :) See how it fits.

Comment: This is utterly marvellous, thanks for the extra effort :)

Comment: @Arronical No problem, it was fun. :) I corrected a typo in the second version, there was an `exit` which should have been a `return`.